# What this line of code does using names and %in%?

Tags: r, names

I was wondering what the code below does.

```
data=mydata[,names(mydata) %in% variables$variable]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`names(mydata) %in% variables$variable` returns a boolean vector of TRUE/FALSE depending on if column names of "mydata" dataset exists in the defined vector `variables$variable` . Hence, with `data=mydata[,names(mydata) %in% variables$variable]` "data" will have all observations (rows) of "mydata" with all columns in `variables$variable`

Answer (score 2):

It subsets the columns of 'mydata' that are also found in the variable column in 'variables'.  It can be also written as

```
mydata[intersect(names(mydata), variables$variable)]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
    select(any_of(variables$variable))
```